# Is it possible to get access to the virtual pointer in a polymorphic class

Tags: c++

Is it possible to get access to the virtual pointer i.e pointer to the virtual table in a polymorphic class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no, the standard is agnostic about how the virtual dispatch is implemented, so as far as it is concerned `virtual` classes may not even have a vptr and a vtable.

The vptr is an implementation detail, you should look at your compiler documentation to check if there's a documented way to access it (but I've never heard of compiler builtins to do this), otherwise you have to look at the assembly output to determine its position.

Out of curiosity, why do you need to access the vptr?

Comment: I wanted to push one of my implementations at run time through code, though this was strictly for experimentation purpose only.

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to do this, since the implementation of polymorphism and dynamic dispatch is implementaiton-specific.

Answer (score 1):

*Many* compilers put the vtable pointer at the beginning of the class, so you could get it by casting your class pointer to a pointer pointer and retrieve it.

But as it has been pointed out, you have to be aware that this is implementation-specific, so if you choose a different compiler, a different compiler version, or a different target platform, it may just randomly break - if you're lucky, it will crash. If not, there'll be a subtle bug somewhere that you'll spend ages trying to debug.

This goes double when you use virtual inheritance on top of it.